# Complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions

Let $C$ denote the unit circle  centered at the origin in Complex Plane

What is the value of

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C |1+z+z^2 |dz,$$ where the integral is taken anti-clockwise along $C$?

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 3

What I have answered is 0 because it seems like $f(z)$ is analytic at 0 hence by Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Be careful! $z\mapsto |1+z+z^2|$ is real-valued and not constant and therefore not holomorphic!

Comment: $|z|$ is not analytic at 0

Comment: Numerically integrating seems to give $\approx 0.6$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To compute $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\mathcal{C} |1+z+z^2|^2 dz$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329248/to-compute-frac12-pi-i-int-mathcalc-1zz22-dz-where-mathcalc)

Comment: @LutzL Actually, it's not a duplicate; the results are different, although the methods are similar. I have provided solutions to both of them. Also, none of the choices in the OP are correct, as also noted by user399601. See my solution below.

Comment: Yes, I see, the square is missing. It should be obvious from the provided results and the topic, complex analysis, that this is a typo, the only interesting question is if this was already wrong in the original task or only here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want the integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C |1+z+z^2|dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|1+z+z^2|z~d\theta$$

since $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Now consider the absolute value portion,

$$
\begin{align}
|1+z+z^2|
&=\sqrt{(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^2)^*}\\
&=\sqrt{(1+z+z^2)(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2})}\\
&=\sqrt{(1+z+z^2)(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2})\frac{z^2}{z^2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+z+z^2}{z} \right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{z}+1+z \right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(1+2\cos\theta)^2}\\
&=|1+2\cos\theta|
\end{align}
$$

We can return to solve the integral

$$
\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C |1+z+z^2|dz
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|1+2\cos\theta|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)~d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|1+2\cos\theta|\cos\theta~d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}\approx0.60900
\end{align}$$

This is in agreement with our own numerical solution as well as that of others noted previously.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Note that if $z = x+yi$ then
$$
\left|1+z+z^2\right| 
  = \left|\left(x^2-y^2+x+1\right) +y(2x+1)i\right|
$$
Now parameterize $C$ as $x = \cos t, y = \sin t$ and $t \in [0,2\pi]$, then
$$
\int_C |1+z+z^2 |dz
  = \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} \left|\left(x^2-y^2+x+1\right) +y(2x+1)i\right|
$$
where $x,y$ are functions of $t$ as in the parameterization. Can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

Put $z=e^{it}, 0\le t\le 2π$ and $dz=i.e^{it}dt$.

So $I_1=\int_0^{2π}|1+e^{it}+e^{i2t}|^2ie^{it}dt=i\int_0^{2π}(1+e^{it}+e^{i2t})(1+e^{-it}+e^{-i2t})e^{it}dt$

$=i\int_0^{2π}g(t)dt$, where $g(t)$ is the integrand and $g(2π+t)=g(t)$. So $I_1=...$

Comment: Why do you put a square on the absolute value? It wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: Cye Waldman..I misread it..