# To compute $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\mathcal{C} |1+z+z^2|^2 dz$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ centred at the origin taken anticlockwise. Compute the value of the integrtal $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\mathcal{C} |1+z+z^2|^2 dz$$

I don't recon we can use the residue theorem to compute this integral because the integrand is not analytic anywhere.

I then tried substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$ and integrating it the traditional way but cant make much of the integrated $|1+e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}|^2$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

Note that on the unit circle $\bar z=1/z$.  Hence, we have on the unit circle

$$\left|z^2+z+1 \right|^2=(z^2+z+1)(\bar z^2+\bar z+1)=(z^2+z+1)\left(\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac1z+1\right)$$

---

Alternatively, using the parameterization proposed in the OP, we an write $dz=ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta$ and

$$\begin{align}
\left|z^2+z+1 \right|^2&=(e^{i2\theta}+e^{i\theta}+1)(e^{-i2\theta}+e^{-i\theta}+1)\\\\&=3+e^{i2\theta}+2e^{i\theta}+e^{-i2\theta}+2e^{-i\theta}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi Mark, nice to *see* you again. I think you have a typo in the last line here, it should read $3+e^{i2\theta}+2e^{i\theta}+e^{-i2\theta}+2e^{-i\theta}$.

Comment: Hi Cye!  How are you?  And I've edited the typo.  Nice catch!

Comment: I'm doing well, thanks. I hope that you are as well. It wasn't so much a *catch* as a step I passed through on the way to my own solution below, as well as here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328658/complex-integral/2329200#2329200, previously. In fact, I was surprised to see this OP on the heels of the author's previous one. BTW, you can take that absolute value term to any real power and the result is always a real number. I just plotted it out this morning.

Answer (score 1):

We want the integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C |1+z+z^2|^2dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|1+z+z^2|^2z~d\theta$$

since $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Now consider the absolute value portion,

$$
\begin{align}
|1+z+z^2|^2
&={(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^2)^*}\\
&={(1+z+z^2)(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2})}\\
&={(1+z+z^2)(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2})\frac{z^2}{z^2}}\\
&={\left(\frac{1+z+z^2}{z} \right)^2}\\
&={\left(\frac{1}{z}+1+z \right)^2}\\
&={(1+2\cos\theta)^2}\\
\end{align}
$$

We can return to solve the integral

$$
\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C |1+z+z^2|^2dz
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(1+2\cos\theta)^2(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)~d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(1+2\cos\theta)^2\cos\theta~d\theta\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

This is in agreement with our own numerical solution.